# summarise (avg) table (keyed) for each row

Tags: kdb

Given a keyed table, e.g.:

```
q)\S 7   / seed random numbers for reproducibility
q)v:flip (neg[d 0]?`1)!#[;prd[d]?12] d:4 6     / 4 cols 6 rows
q)show kt:([]letter:d[1]#.Q.an)!v
letter| c  g b  e 
------| ----------
a     | 11 0 3  9 
b     | 11 8 10 0 
c     | 7  2 2  3 
d     | 8  4 9  6 
e     | 0  0 5  0 
f     | 1  0 0  11
```

How to calculate an average for each row --- e.g. `(c+g+b+e)%4` --- for any number of columns?

Comment: feedback from the downvoter how the question and answer can be improved would be much welcome

Answer (score 1):

Following on from your own solution, note that you have to be a little careful with null handling. Your approach won't ignore nulls in the way that `avg` normally would.

```
q).[`kt;("a";`g);:;0N];
q)update av:avg flip value kt from kt
letter| c  g b  e  av
------| ---------------
a     | 11   3  9
b     | 11 8 10 0  7.25
c     | 7  2 2  3  3.5
d     | 8  4 9  6  6.75
e     | 0  0 5  0  1.25
f     | 1  0 0  11 3
```

To make it ignore nulls you have to avg `each` row  rather than averaging the flip.

```
q)update av:avg each value kt from kt
letter| c  g b  e  av
------| -------------------
a     | 11   3  9  7.666667
b     | 11 8 10 0  7.25
c     | 7  2 2  3  3.5
d     | 8  4 9  6  6.75
e     | 0  0 5  0  1.25
f     | 1  0 0  11 3
```

Answer (score -1):

**Solution 1: q-sql**

```
q)update av:avg flip value kt from kt
letter| c  g b  e  av  
------| ---------------
a     | 11 0 3  9  5.75
b     | 11 8 10 0  7.25
c     | 7  2 2  3  3.5 
d     | 8  4 9  6  6.75
e     | 0  0 5  0  1.25
f     | 1  0 0  11 3
```

**Solution 2: [functional q-sql](https://code.kx.com/q/basics/funsql/)**

tl;dr:

```
q)![kt;();0b;](1#`av)!enlist(avg;)enlist,cols[`kt]except cols key`kt
letter| c  g b  e  av  
------| ---------------
a     | 11 0 3  9  5.75
b     | 11 8 10 0  7.25
c     | 7  2 2  3  3.5 
d     | 8  4 9  6  6.75
e     | 0  0 5  0  1.25
f     | 1  0 0  11 3
```

let's start with a look how the [parse tree](https://code.kx.com/q/basics/parsetrees/) of a non-general solution would look like:

```
q)parse"update av:avg (c;g;b;e) from kt"
!
`kt
()
0b
(,`av)!,(avg;(enlist;`c;`g;`b;`e))
```

(note that q is a wrapper implemented in k, so the `,` prefix operator in the above expression is the same as `enlist` keyword in q)

so all the below are equivalent (verify with [~](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/match/)). relying on projection: `(x;y)~(x;)y`, we can further improve the readability by reducing the distance between parens:

```
q)k)(!;`kt;();0b;(,`av)!,(avg;(enlist;`c;`g;`b;`e)))
q)(!;`kt;();0b;(enlist`av)!enlist(avg;(enlist;`c;`g;`b;`e)))
q)(!;`kt;();0b;(1#`av)!enlist(avg;(enlist;`c;`g;`b;`e)))
q)(!;`kt;();0b;)(1#`av)!enlist(avg;)(enlist;`c;`g;`b;`e)
```

let's evaluate the parse tree to check:

```
q)eval(!;`kt;();0b;)(1#`av)!enlist(avg;)(enlist;`c;`g;`b;`e)

letter| c  g b  e  av  
------| ---------------
a     | 11 0 3  9  5.75
b     | 11 8 10 0  7.25
c     | 7  2 2  3  3.5 
d     | 8  4 9  6  6.75
e     | 0  0 5  0  1.25
f     | 1  0 0  11 3
```

`` (enlist;`c;`g;`b;`e) `` in the general case is:

```
q)enlist,cols[`kt]except cols key`kt
enlist
`c
`g
`b
`e
```

so let's plug in and check:

```
q)eval(!;`kt;();0b;(1#`av)!enlist(avg;)enlist,cols[`kt]except cols key`kt)
letter| c  g b  e  av  
------| ---------------
a     | 11 0 3  9  5.75
b     | 11 8 10 0  7.25
c     | 7  2 2  3  3.5 
d     | 8  4 9  6  6.75
e     | 0  0 5  0  1.25
f     | 1  0 0  11 3
```

also:

```
q)![`kt;();0b;(1#`av)!enlist(avg;)enlist,cols[`kt]except cols key`kt]
q)![ kt;();0b;](1#`av)!enlist(avg;)enlist,cols[`kt]except cols key`kt
```